# R code optimization

Tags: performance, r, memory-optimization

I have about 977 obs in `top500Stocks` which contains name of 977 stocks.

```
head(top500Stocks,10)
    ï..Symbol
1    RELIANCE
2         TCS
3    HDFCBANK
4        INFY
5  HINDUNILVR
6        HDFC
7   ICICIBANK
8   KOTAKBANK
9        SBIN
10 BAJFINANCE
```

and I have Date, OHLC and Adj.Close, Vol and Ret of each stocks from the top500Stocks in stocksRetData

```
  head(stocksRetData[[1]],3)
          Date     Open     High      Low    Close Adj.Close    Volume   Ret
    1 20000103 28.18423 29.86935 28.18423 38.94457  29.86935  28802010 0.000
    2 20000104 30.66445 32.26056 29.82188 42.06230  32.26056  61320457 0.080
    3 20000105 30.45677 34.16522 30.45677 43.71014  33.52440 173426953 0.039
```

Now for a given lookbackPeriod  and holdPeriod I am trying to run the below function but it takes about 1 minute. How can I make it faster? Because I have to run for multiple lookbackPeriod and holdPeriod it will take forever to complete.

```
CalC.MOD_MScore.Ret.High <- function(lookbackPeriod, holdPeriod, fnoStocks, 
                                     stocksRetData, totalTestPeriod) {
  
  #We go through each stock and calculate Modified mscores where we give more importance to recent data
  
  WeeklyData <- list()
  wmean <- function(x, k) mean(seq(k)/k * x)
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(fnoStocks)){
    
    out <- stocksRetData[[i]]
    out <- tail(out,totalTestPeriod)
    
    if (nrow(out)==totalTestPeriod){
      
      tempDF <- transform(out, wtMean = rollapply(Ret, lookbackPeriod, wmean, 
                                                  k = lookbackPeriod, align = "right", 
                                                  fill = NA))
      
      tempDF <- transform(tempDF, ExitVal = rollapply(lead(High, holdPeriod), 
                                                      holdPeriod, max, 
                                                      align = "right", 
                                                        fill = NA))
      
      tempDF$NWeekRet <- (tempDF$ExitVal - tempDF$Adj.Close ) / tempDF$Adj.Close
      
      tempDF <- tempDF[!is.na(tempDF$wtMean),]
      tempDF <- tempDF[!is.na(tempDF$ExitVal),]
      tempDF$StockName = fnoStocks[i,1]
      tempDF$WeekNum = c((lookbackPeriod):(nrow(tempDF)+lookbackPeriod-1))
      
      WeeklyData[[i]] <- data.frame(
        StockName = tempDF$StockName,
        WeekNum = tempDF$WeekNum,
        M_Score = tempDF$wtMean,
        NWeekRet = tempDF$NWeekRet,
        stringsAsFactors =  FALSE
      )
      
    }
  }# i ends here
  
  return(bind_rows(WeeklyData))
}
```

This takes more than a minute to complete.

```
 a <- CalC.MOD_MScore.Ret.High(4,14,fnoStocks = top500Stocks, stocksRetData = stocksRetData, 2000)
```

Comment: can you supply the data so the code can be tested?

Comment: @minem sure but where do I upload it?

Comment: @minem top500Stocks contains 977 unique strings in column 1. And stocksRetData contains list of 977 dataframes with data in above format. Other than that no other data is used.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Stupid_Intern updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fake data:

```
set.seed(1)
n1 <- 977
top500Stocks <- data.frame(a = sample(letters, n1, replace = T))
n <- 2000
df <- data.frame(High = rnorm(n),
                 Adj.Close = rnorm(n),
                 Ret = rnorm(n))
stocksRetData <- lapply(1:n1, function(x) df)
```

new function:

```
require(data.table)
minem <- function(lookbackPeriod, holdPeriod, fnoStocks, stocksRetData, totalTestPeriod) {
  
  WeeklyData <- list()
  k <- lookbackPeriod
  y <- seq(k)/k/k
  wmean2 <- function(x) sum(y * x)
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(fnoStocks)) {
    
    out <- tail(stocksRetData[[i]], totalTestPeriod)
    
    if (nrow(out) == totalTestPeriod) {
      
      wtMean <- frollapply(out$Ret, k, wmean2, align = "right", fill = NA)
      ExitVal <- frollapply(lead(out$High, holdPeriod), 
                            holdPeriod, max, align = "right", fill = NA)
      tempDF <- out
      tempDF$wtMean <- wtMean
      tempDF$ExitVal <- ExitVal
      tempDF$NWeekRet <- (ExitVal / tempDF$Adj.Close - 1)
      
      tempDF <- tempDF[!is.na(wtMean),]
      tempDF <- tempDF[!is.na(tempDF$ExitVal),]
      tempDF$StockName = fnoStocks[i, 1]
      tempDF$WeekNum = c(k:(nrow(tempDF) + k - 1))
      
      WeeklyData[[i]] <- tempDF[, c('StockName', 'WeekNum', 'wtMean', 'NWeekRet')]
      colnames(WeeklyData[[i]])[3] <- 'M_Score'
    }
  }# i ends here
  return(bind_rows(WeeklyData))
}
```

speed:

```
system.time(a2 <- minem(4, 14, top500Stocks, stocksRetData, 2000))
# user  system elapsed 
# 2.36    0.00    2.36
```

(versus 31.75 seconds for original on my machine)

some comments:

1. from code profiling we see that `wmean` was the slowest part(called thousands of times). As we know `k`(lookbackPeriod) beforehand we can simplify/speedup this function.
2. `rollapply` was quite slow. replacing it with `data.table`s `frollapply` we gain performance
3. creating new `data.frame` in loop isn't efficient, we can reuse `tempDF` (but this isn't as significant as first two points)
4. other minor changes

### update

we can go faster:

```
minem2 <- function(lookbackPeriod, holdPeriod, fnoStocks, 
                  stocksRetData, totalTestPeriod) {
  
  k <- lookbackPeriod
  y <- seq(k)/k/k
  
  # create stock name data.table
  sn <- data.table(sname = fnoStocks[[1]], id = 1:nrow(fnoStocks), key = 'id')
  dt <- rbindlist(stocksRetData[1:nrow(fnoStocks)], idcol = 'id') # bind together data
  setkey(dt, id)
  dt <- dt[, tail(.SD, totalTestPeriod), by = id] # select last n rows by group
  dt[sn, StockName := sname] # merge stock names
  
  # calculate wtMean using tcrossprod:
  v <- shift(dt$Ret, (k:1) - 1L) # create list of lagged values
  v <- do.call(cbind, v) # bind together
  dt[, wtMean := tcrossprod(y, v)[1, ]]
  dt[1:(k - 1), wtMean := NA, by = id] # delete first (k-1) as they aren't correct
  # maybe not needed
  
  # the same approach for ExitVal as it was sufficiently fast
  dt[, ExitVal := frollapply(lead(High, holdPeriod), holdPeriod, max,
                             align = "right", fill = NA), by = id]
  
  dt[, NWeekRet := (ExitVal / Adj.Close - 1)]
  dt <- dt[!is.na(wtMean) & !is.na(ExitVal)]
  dt[, WeekNum := c(k:(.N + k - 1)), by = id]
  res <- dt[, .(StockName, WeekNum, M_Score = wtMean, NWeekRet)]
  return(res[])
}

system.time(a3 <- minem2(4, 14, top500Stocks, stocksRetData, 2000))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.91    0.01    0.78
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works wonderfully. :)